What are use-cases and/or pros and cons of having a named namespace within an unnamed namespace?
The following "named namespace within unnamed namespace" scenario is allowed (as I understand it):
namespace foo {
    namespace {
        namespace bar {
            int baz() { return 42; };
        } // bar
    } // unnamed

    int frob() {
        return bar::baz();
    }
} // foo

int froz() {
    return foo::bar::baz();
}

Is applying this considered a pattern / an anti-pattern (compared to not having the bar namespace within the unnamed namespace)?  Are there any use-cases (beyond the ones below) for using such a namespace within an unnamed namespace?
The following use-cases came to my mind, which are somehow unusual and don't represent the "everyday" way of coding:

In an existing namespace hierarchy, say, a::b::internal, with stuff from internal only being used in the same translation unit, adding an unnamed namespace "in between" like a::b::<unnamed>::internal does not break existing code that explicitly refers to the internal sub namespace.
If there is lots of stuff in the unnamed namespace you might want to have some sub-structuring.  (Maybe you better re-design your file-structure...)
When bringing together different parts of source code within the same namespace in the same compilation unit by #includeing them, this might allow some hacks - I myself, however, could not even think about something here that could not be solved nicely without that feature.


A namespace like foo can be used from any translation unit, and can be added to without control. An anonymous namespace is local to the current translation unit, and so are all nested namespaces inside it. So bar is a local namespace inside that specific translation unit, it can't be accessed or added to from any other translation unit. Basically what you said yourself in your first bullet point. It's useful for "internal" code or variables that you don't want to polute the global namespace with.

pro/con compared to what?

This trick isn't supposed to be used in a header file? If it is, then it will likely result in ODR violation.

Looks like a list type question.
